# Shouldln't a Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a test webpage (code shown below) to see if I can create a webpage that includes a working Facebook "like" button.  When I view my test page in a browser, the like button appears with a thumbs-up as expected.  Clicking on the like button elicits a login prompt.  Following the login prompt (i.e., logging in) causes the thumbs-up to be replaced with a check mark and the word, "Like".  At this point, shouldn't I also see the number of likes (which I'm thinking would be 1, my own).  I do not see any such number.  Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?  BTW, the debugger seems to be happy.  Thanks.  Here's my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>FB Like Test</title>
  <meta property="og:image" content="Long Absolute URL to Image" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="A Walking Tour of the New Orleans French Quarter" />
  <meta property="og:url" BTWcontent="http://www.djolley.net/posts/2017/0118A.html" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="A walking tour designed to acquaint tourists with the major points of interest in the New Orleans French Quarter." />
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">FB Like Test</h2>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div style="display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 12px;" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.djolley.net/posts/2017/0118A.html" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn’t a question title. (Be a full sentence maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `data-layout="standard"`. The button layout does not show the number of likes. You can also use `button_count` or `box_count`.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button